# How to have 2 Edge browser windows in a kiosk account?

Tags: multiple-monitors, browser, window, kiosk

In our workplace, we are running into a scenario where the best option would be to run 2 webpages in a kiosk account, with a fullscreen Edge window on each of 2 monitors. I have already tested and you can do a fullscreen window on each monitor on a regular windows setup, but it seems the shortcut to create a new window is missing in kiosk mode.

I have found a couple forums where it was mentioned in Edge v89 that feature was removed from kiosk accounts. I am just wondering if it's possible to re-enable that somehow, whether it's with the use of an XML provisioning package, or something like that, but I can't find a single good resource online.

Also, the option to create a new window isn't available whether you setup the kiosk with the option "As a digital sign or interactive display" or "As a public browser."

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Chrome instead of Edge for my solution, but it works either way. This solution will allow you to open multiple Chrome kiosk browser windows on multiple monitors.
Create a batch file and paste in the following code:

```
start chrome --app="www.google.com" --kiosk --window-position=-1920,0 --user-data-dir=C:\monitor1
start chrome --app="www.google.com" --kiosk --window-position=0,0 --user-data-dir=C:\monitor2
```

`--kiosk` will make Chrome launch in fullscreen in kiosk mode

`--window-position` will set, in pixels, with what offset to create the window at. In my case I have 2 monitors, with the main one on the right. Not sure why, but the pixel count index seems to start on the main monitor, so if you have multiple monitors with monitors to the left of the main one, you will have to negatively index to create a window there.

`--user-data-dir` is necessary because if a Chrome process is running, if you launch a new Chrome window with arguments, those arguments just get added to the currently running Chrome process. The user data dir will force Chrome to create a new profile for each, meaning each process can have it's own launch arguments that are applied separately. You can manually set this, but Chrome will create the directories as long as it has permissions to do so.

If for whatever reason that doesn't work for you, you can use multiple web browsers without the `--user-data-dir` argument set.

This is NOT a solution to adding multiple windows of a web browser in an assigned access kiosk account in windows. That is impossible as of Edge v89. This answer is a workaround solution.

Answer (score 1):

By using this you will get 2 Edge windows in kiosk mode:

```
start msedge --new-window --kiosk https://github.com/
start msedge --new-window --kiosk https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Tested out on Edge Version 113.0.1774.42 (Official build) (64-bit) - the latest version at the moment.

Comment: This is a really good start, thank you. I am having some problems though. What I tried was creating a batch file with the script you gave and putting it in shell:startup folder. One the local admin account it works fine, but on the kiosk account, it just opens one window of Edge with the url I specified when I created the kiosk account. How would you go about implementing this for a kiosk account? And thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome! :) Hmm. What does it happen if you launch the batch file as an administrator on the kiosk account? Do both windows open?

Comment: Since it's a kiosk account, I can't open file explorer or actually anything. The only app you can run is Edge. I'm not sure how I would run the batch file once I logged in... Unless you have some ideas? I know in active directory you can set a batch file to run when a user logs in... But unfortunately kiosk accounts are local and not domain accounts. the shell:startup folder is the only thing I could think of.

Comment: @justdoingmyjob - You should be able to open a shortcut to Edge with the arguments `--new-window --kiosk https://github.com/`

Comment: I can definitely see what you're saying... I added these arguments onto a Edge shortcut file: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --new-window https://github.com/ --new-window https://github.com/` commands to open 2 windows but it instead opened 2 github pages in the same window. Seems like it should work. I wonder if Microsoft has somehow disabled more than 1 window on kiosk mode on a more fundamental level so that fix isn't possible. Regardless, I think maybe the answer is that it can't be done.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think you can run a bat file since [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-policies) restrictions are set. It seems you could run multiple apps with [multi-app kiosk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps), but you need to run a specific Windows 10 build. Then you can do it like [here](https://superuser.com/a/1716099/1124080).

Comment: Opening new windows from in kiosk mode for Edge is blocked according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode#use-kiosk-mode-features:~:text=Y-,CTRL%2BN%20blocked%20(open%20a%20new%20window)%20*,Y,-CTRL%2BT%20blocked). Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher) would help you? Also, maybe you could use [this](https://support.intuiface.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007433831-Using-kiosk-mode-on-Windows-PCs-to-prevent-OS-access) as an alternative?

Comment: @rd51 Thanks for that link, I didn't come across that earlier. Very helpful. I have tried to setup a multi-app kiosk, but it looks like to make it work I will have to use a specific windows version. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: You're welcome! Sure, let me know! Good luck with it! :)

Comment: @rd51 So... good news and bad news. The mult-app kiosk DOES allow you to create multiple windows of Edge... but the problem is, it doesn't recognize the 2nd monitor. When You drag it to the sides, the window doesn't appear on the 2nd monitor, only the option to do split-screen. I have made a ticket with microsoft about this. But honestly, not expecting anything to come of it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hmm. There might be a solution, but I'll have to look into it tomorrow. The thing is there's a software that lets you run two different instances of an OS at the same time, but then you'd need to use 2 mice and 2 keyboards. But I suppose there must be a device (it must be strictly hardware) that can make a mouse and a keyboard control 2 OSes at the same time. Unfortunately, that software is paid if I recall correctly. I forgot its name, that's why I'll have to look for it. I also know it wasn't the only software like this, and I'm not talking about virtual machines.

Comment: Found this quote directly from microsoft: "The use of multiple monitors isn't support on multi-app kiosk mode."
Thanks a lot, Microsoft.

Comment: @rd51 Don't think would work in this scenario. We are pretty limited space-wise since the tables barely have enough room for the keyboard and mouse as it is... This might be a last resort but it's nice to know the option exists. Thanks. Also, the mini-PCs we are using only have 8GB of ram, so I wonder if that would be enough for windows 10 to function properly with 2 OSs?

Comment: Ah, Microsoft said no. The program that I used is called [SoftXpand](https://xpressnet.co.nz/soft-xpand/), but that only works with Windows 7. There's another one, [Aster](https://www.ibik.ru/), and this one covers the latest Windows editions, including W10. Both programs have free trials, so you can test at least for Aster how your PCs will behave. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhNE2GGWj-o) for Aster. You should also look on google for Aster alternatives, in case it doesn't suit you.

Comment: @rd51 That actually would work! And it looks like you would possibly only need 1 KB / mouse for it based on the product description and pictures. I ended up biting the bullet and deciding to not use a kiosk assigned access windows account, but a web browser in kiosk mode. Not as locked down as I would have liked but works well enough. You can read my answer if you want more info. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm glad you have sorted it out in the end! You are welcome! :)